# Alfresco WS Client API - WSSecurityException when using fetchMore method

Tags: web-services, authentication, alfresco

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code here... I'm always getting this exception on the first call to **contentService.read(...)** after the first fetchMore has occurred.

**org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized**

```
// Here we're setting the endpoint address manually, this way we don't need to use
// webserviceclient.properties
WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress(wsRepositoryEndpoint);
AuthenticationUtils.startSession(wsUsername, wsPassword);

// Set the batch size in the query header
int batchSize = 5000;
QueryConfiguration queryCfg = new QueryConfiguration();
queryCfg.setFetchSize(batchSize);

RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService();
repositoryService.setHeader(new RepositoryServiceLocator().getServiceName().getNamespaceURI(), "QueryHeader", queryCfg);

ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

String luceneQuery = buildLuceneQuery(categories, properties);

// Call the repository service to do search based on category
Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, luceneQuery);

// Execute the query
QueryResult queryResult = repositoryService.query(STORE, query, true);

String querySession = queryResult.getQuerySession();
while (querySession != null) {            
    ResultSet resultSet = queryResult.getResultSet();
    ResultSetRow[] rows = resultSet.getRows();
    for (ResultSetRow row : rows) {
        // Read the content from the repository
        Content[] readResult = contentService.read(new Predicate(new Reference[] { new Reference(STORE, row.getNode().getId(), null) },
            STORE, null), Constants.PROP_CONTENT);
        Content content = readResult[0];
        [...]
    }            
    // Get the next batch of results
    queryResult = repositoryService.fetchMore(querySession);
    // process subsequent query results
    querySession = queryResult.getQuerySession();
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using the WS Client? It's removed from Alfresco 5.0 and since version 2.2 their hasn't really been done anything to it. So switch to CMIS WS to be better off in terms of support, future proof etc.

Comment: The only requirement I have is to be able to perform queries based on tags and custom properties (we've defined custom aspects in Alfresco)... will I be able to do that using CMIS WS? Which library would you suggest? OpenCMIS from Apache Chemistry?

Comment: Yep custom aspects are working. If you have a CMIS 1.1 Alfresco then you don't need anything else. if you're on 1.0, then you need additional the OpenCMIS Extension library

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take a look at it soon. If OpenCMIS allows me to do what I want and if queries performance are better, I will be glad to make the switch.

Comment: If you switch to CMIS AtomPub binding then your requests will be much smaller and will def be fasters than the current Soap API or the CMIS WS